# select box issue in IE when using BOXOVER.js tool tip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xhtml

I am using boxover.js tool tip:

http://www.koders.com/javascript/fid8780CBE6D1BEE164FC239AA55DCB13A53B3536E8.aspx?s=document#L6

The tool tip works well with all the elements except SELECT box in IE.

I have a code where i need to show some image as a tool tip on selecting the option in a select box.

Ex:

```
<select name="categoryName" id="categoryName" style="width:50%;" size="10" >
    <option value="">--Select Category--</option>
    <option title="cssbody=[bdycss] cssheader=[hdrcss] header=[Category] body=[<center><p><img src='icon1.png'></p>]" value="1">category1</option>
    <option title="cssbody=[bdycss] cssheader=[hdrcss] header=[Category] body=[<center><p><img src='icon2.png'></p>]" value="2">category2</option>
    <option title="cssbody=[bdycss] cssheader=[hdrcss] header=[Category] body=[<center><p><img src='icon3.png'></p>]" value="3">category3</option>      
</select>
```

Pls help me in fixing this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you using?

Answer (score 1):

IE6 does not [IE7 onwards it does] support title property for OPTION tag. You can have same title for all OPTIONs by setting title attribute in SELECT tag.

Another option is to have DHTML popup as tooltip.

Comment: I can see the title contents in IE also. But the issue is it is not taking the BOXOVER.js styles

Comment: When hovered or clicked on the option... tt shows the contents in the title as
eg: cssbody=[bdycss] cssheader=[hdrcss] header=[Category] body=[<center><p><img src='icon1.png'></p>]